# How can I use my own shell as the login shell?

Tags: command-line, chsh

Suppose that I have a mini-shell, named `minish` which provides only `cd`, `ls`, `rm`, `mkdir`, etc. `minish` is saved in `~/Desktop/Shell`. It can be used from other shell, such as `bash`, by calling just `~/Desktop/Shell/minish`. It works well.

But to use it as the login shell, I added `~/Desktop/Shell/minish` at the bottom of `/etc/shells` and execute `chsh` and typed `~/Desktop/Shell/minish`, but it says `minish` is an invalid shell.

I guessed 2 possibilities of this error:

- Because `minish` is not in `/bin` since other shells are all in `/bin`.
- Because there are some qualifications to be called as a **shell**, so not any executable file can not be a **shell**, my `minish` either.

If the second case is the reason, what are those qualifications or necessaries and how `chsh` checks this conditions? Or is there any other reason?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put `~/Desktop/Shell/minish` verbatim in `/etc/shells`; the expansion of `~` is a shell feature and likely unsupported by whatever application parses `/etc/shells`, because it wouldn't know, to whose home directory `~` is supposed to refer. Instead, you need to use the full path name, e. g. `/home/analysis/Desktop/Shell/minish`.